# append dropdown menus with multiple ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

ok so I've been working on this call:

```
$('#FirstCategory').change(function () {
$('#result').empty();
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
  str += $( this ).attr('id') + " ";
});
$.ajax({
    url:'/dev_integrapp/profile/product/'+str,
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{parent:str},
    success:function(data){
        $('#result').append("<select id='SecondCategory'></select>");
        for(var i in data){
            var obj=data[i];
            for(var j in obj){
                var id=obj[j].id;
                var name=obj[j].name;
                $('#SecondCategory').append("<option id='"+id+"'>"+id+" - "+name+"</option>");
            }

        }
    }
});
})
 .change();
```

Then if you select one of the options from the second category, it will make a similar call to display a third dropdown menu, which should be doing the same thing but doesn't. The third menu never let's me select anything. It shows me the right options though but if I click it it just stays in the first line which is "select sub-menu". What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dynamically added items you need to use `.on` to bind event handlers:

```
$('body').on('change', '#SecondCategory', function () { 

})
```

Why? : http://api.jquery.com/on/

> **Event handlers** (e.g., .click()) are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.
>
> **Delegated** events (e.g., .on('click')) have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: Dude thanks so much! how come this works with newly added divs? care to explain just a bit the theory? I've been dealing with this for a while and I know I can't have a script that acts on a DOM element that's not there yet but this seemed to work just fine, how come?